# undo git pull in a rails app

Tags: git, heroku

I accidently pulled an update from rails app on heroku which has messed up my local code.

Is there any way to undo this stuff.

I was trying to commit some changes I made locally to bitbucked, then I got the error that I need to pull and then only I can commit. When I pulled, I see that my local code is messed up.

Any way to undo the git pull heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you need to `reset` your `HEAD` to where it was before. You can do `git log` to get to the commit in which you were working before, and after that, write the following command:

```
get reset `sha1 of that commit`
```

Answer (score 1):

if

> git pull heroku

is the last command, meaning you didn't change branch or did commits or anything.

> git reset HEAD~1

will do the trick, else you will need to run

> get reset `sha1 of that commit just before git pull merges`

**(hopefully you dont have to go this far)**
while doing git pull, if it rebased instead of merge, then you will have to find the sha1 sum using

> git reflog

Answer (score 0):

The good news: you cannot destroy anything by pulling. You have simply added a few commits on top of your last and made your branch point to a different commit, easily undone.

```
git log                      # find the commit you want to go back to, let's call it a1b2b123b123
git branch BRANCH a1b2b123b123 --force    # substitute your real branch name for BRANCH
git checkout BRANCH
```

Save the output of `git log` so you have something to hold on to in case you get lost.

The stuff added by the pull will be garbage collected after a while.